# How can i get this certain part of the command output using shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I am on `iOS`, im working on a project, I'm using bash/shell. I need to just print this: `5EF31D4F-4C1E-432A-8BDD-D06A1697C33B`, from this:

```
HUANG:/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application root# find . -name "Safari" -ls    
  4426    0 drwxr-xr-x   3 mobile   mobile        306 Oct 17 18:41 ./5EF31D4F-4C1E-432A-8BDD-D06A1697C33B/Library/Safari
HUANG:/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application root#
```

The string part I'm trying to print is random for every device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -name "Safari" -ls | cut -d/ -f 2
```

Use `cut` to extract the desired part from the output.

- `d/`: set '/' as the delimeter
- `-f 2`: print only the second field

Comment: I wanted to post the same answer, I only replaced `-ls` with `-print`.